# Fix OpenSSL CCS vulnerability on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: upgrade, ssl, openssl

I just installed an SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt on one of my domains. Everything was fine, green lock icon on Chrome. But just to be sure, I checked the domain on ssllabs.com. And to my surprise, It has the worst rating, an F. It seems that my server is vulnerable to OpenSSL CCS vulnerability (CVE-2014-0224).

My server runs Ubuntu 14.04. I tried to update the packages and install a new version of OpenSSL.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssl libssl-dev
```

I couldn't find any new update so I built it from source. But now that I have the latest version, I don't see any difference when I check the domain on SSLLabs, it is still rated F.

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2f 28 Jan 2016
```

What should I do to fix this vulnerability once and for all ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CVE-2014-0224 has been patched in June 2014.

Run `apt-get changelog openssl | grep -A10 0224` to make sure.

```
 $ apt-get changelog openssl | grep -A10 0224
    - debian/patches/CVE-2014-0224-regression2.patch: accept CCS after
      sending finished ssl/s3_clnt.c.

 -- Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com>  Fri, 20 Jun 2014 13:57:48 -0400

openssl (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.15) precise-security; urgency=medium

  * SECURITY UPDATE: regression with tls_session_secret_cb (LP:
#1329297)
    - debian/patches/CVE-2014-0224.patch: set the CCS_OK flag when using
      tls_session_secret_cb for session resumption in ssl/s3_clnt.c.

 -- Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com>  Thu, 12 Jun 2014 08:30:56 -0400

openssl (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.14) precise-security; urgency=medium

  * SECURITY UPDATE: arbitrary code execution via DTLS invalid fragment
    - debian/patches/CVE-2014-0195.patch: add consistency check for DTLS
      fragments in ssl/d1_both.c.
    - CVE-2014-0195
--
    - debian/patches/CVE-2014-0224-1.patch: only accept change cipher spec
      when it is expected in ssl/s3_clnt.c, ssl/s3_pkt.c, ssl/s3_srvr.c,
      ssl/ssl3.h.
    - debian/patches/CVE-2014-0224-2.patch: don't accept zero length master
      secrets in ssl/s3_pkt.c.
    - debian/patches/CVE-2014-0224-3.patch: allow CCS after resumption in
      ssl/s3_clnt.c.
    - CVE-2014-0224   * SECURITY UPDATE: denial of service via ECDH null session cert
    - debian/patches/CVE-2014-3470.patch: check session_cert is not NULL
      before dereferencing it in ssl/s3_clnt.c.
    - CVE-2014-3470

 -- Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com>  Mon, 02 Jun 2014 14:05:34 -0400

openssl (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.13) precise-security; urgency=medium

  * SECURITY UPDATE: denial of service via use after free
```